# limit size of text file without using log4net or NLog

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, text-files

I am developing a  winForm application in which I have a text file for logging purpose. I want to limit its size to 3 MB so that if this limit is passed and new data is written then the oldest data in text file is deleted to make space for new data. any useful suggestion ?

I know we have some logging framework (e.g. NLog or log4net, both available from NuGet) which provides rolling log files feature. But i  dont want to use it as I have just one text file in the whole project.

I wnat to read starting at the beginning of the file, delete some data and then append new data at the end.

Thanks

Comment: when opening log file you can get its size and take actions if it reached the limit or not

Comment: `but i dont want to use it as I have just one text file in the whole project` Of course most commonly everybody uses only one log file. Why that forces you to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: yes i know. u mean FileInfi.Length. But how to delete text from the start of file

Comment: you cant do random access in text files.Or read the whole file and change the line/s you want,or as each line you read you write it to a new file(changing the ones you need) and then replacing it,or a whole new approach with xml for example...

Comment: Manipulating "existing" text in a file is a relatively costly process, to my understanding. Simply appending it isn't a problem, but if you want to go and remove, say, the first 10 lines, then append, it gets a bit more difficult (See Roy Dictus' answer). Why don't you want to use an existing logging framework?

Answer (score 3):

Rolling log files does not mean that the oldest data in a text file gets deleted. It means that after a certain time or a certain file size, a new log file is created.

Text files cannot be deleted from, they are sequential files. So if you want to remove a line from a text file, you must read the file, delete the line from memory and overwrite the file again, OR create a new file and copy line per line to it, skipping the one(s) that you want to "delete".